# Custom Role Provider not working on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database, roleprovider

I have created a custom role provider linked to my dbcontext and it is working as expected when testing on localhost with changes showing immediately on change of the roleID. When I deploy this to Azure and change the roleid the rights of the previous value are retained even when I close the browser and login again. My role provider is as follows:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="MyApp.Providers.MyAppProvider, MyApp" connectionStringName="MyAppContext"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Do I need to add anything to my role provider to make this work in Azure? Is there anything different or specific about getting the role manager to work here?